# PhpUnit throws catched exception

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

I have following php code which i want to test.

```
class A
{
    private $testObject;

    public function __construct($testObject)
    {
        $this->testObject = $testObject;
    }

    public function save()
    {
        try {
           $this->testObject->doSomething();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log($e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The method `doSomething()` eventually throw an exception, thats why its surrounded with a try and catch.

```
class ATest
{
    public function testSaveOnError()
    {
        $testObjectMock= $this->getMock(TestObject::class, ['doSomething'], [], '', false);
        $testObjectMock
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('doSomething')
            ->willThrowException(new \Exception());

        $a = new A($testObjectMock);
        $this->assertFalse($a->save());
    }
}
```

The test runs green but the catched exception is thrown and logged in the phpunit console.
Is there a way to disable exception tracing in UnitTests or am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Why do you configure the mock to throw an Exception? The "save" method does not throw.

Comment: Sorry the code was wrong, updated...

Comment: If the test is green then everything is fine. Try to remove ```error_log``` from the ```save``` method.

Comment: Yea youre right. If i remove ```error_log``` the exception isnt traced. But i want that exception to be logged in my log files.

Answer (score 0):

No `error_log` is a native function. Use logging wrapper to be able to mock it and assert what's logged in case of exception. If anything like [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) is overkill for your needs, you can write your own:

```
class MyLogger
{
    public function log($str) {
        error_log($str)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock the call to error_log(). You can replace it with a psr-3 compatible logging library or wrap it with a simple class as it already has been suggested. This is the cleanest approach IMHO.

But there is another way, if you don't want to change the code under test: override error_log in the current namespace:

```
namespace N;

function error_log()
{
    ATest::logCalled = true;
}
class ATest
{
    public static $logCalled = false;
   ... 
}
```

Now if A is also in namespace N, the unqualified call to error_log (i.e. without leading backslash) will use the function from the namespace in the test.

If you want, you can use the static property logCalled to assert if it has been called.